# Prove Abelian group $G$ is finitely generated iff $G/pG = 0 $ for some prime $p$

Tags: group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Prove Abelian group $G$ is finitely generated iff $G/pG = 0 $ for some prime $p$.

I suppose the question is asking us to consider $G$ as a $ \mathbb{Z} $- module.

Suppose $G$ is finitely generated:

We may write $G = C_{a_1} \times \cdots \times C_{a_k} $ for $a_1 | ... | a_k$. Then my initial thought is we need to pick a prime that will kill everything off in $G$, so perhaps some $p|a_1 $ will work. However I do not see how $G/pG = 0 $ is this case.

I thought $G/pG = \{g+ pG : g \in G\} $ so if we think of the elements of $G$ as integers (modulo something), and $pG$ as these integers multiplied by $p$, it seems like $G/pG$ is simply quotienting $G$ by another factor so potentially not much cancels.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}$ is finitely generated, but $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: Indeed, so what could the question be asking then?

Comment: Is there some module based definition that makes sense which means something different to standard coset notation of groups?

Comment: @EvgenyT I've no idea. Where did you take this question from? Perhaps some translation problem?

Comment: @DonAntonio Actually you have $2G = 0$ in that example, but $G/3G = 0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Isn't $5C_6=C_6$?

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, thanks. I deleted another comment and forgot this one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Indeed, my bad. The integers is a great example.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yours was still a good example that the other direction also fails. I think the most that can be said is that if the group is finite (equivalently finitely generated and torsion) then such a prime exists.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I know, and I wanted to give $\;G:=\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_2\oplus\ldots\;$ , and $\;G/3G=0\;$ as a example in the other direction, but wrote $\;2\;$ instead of three, deleted the whole thing and then your comment and lisyarus' came in...I was also distracted by the question the AP raised in one of his comments: what could the actual question mean? I can't tell...

Comment: Actually, we can slightly strengthen my previous statement to the group having finite exponent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But that would assume that for every exponent $e$, there is a prime $p$ with $p \equiv 1 \mod{e}$. If I remember correctly, that was either not yet proven or really hard to show, wasn't it?

Comment: @Bemte Good point. It works for finite groups because for large enough primes the map $x \mapsto px$ is injective and thus surjective. The statement you have there almost follows from Dirichlet plus CRT, but not quite as the exponents might not be coprime, so the CRT part could fail and I have not thought through if that is fixable.

Comment: (Very late comment) but the actual question is probably: prove that a finitely generated Abelian group $G$ is finite iff $G/pG = 0$ for some prime $p$.